# how to link facebook logged in page with button

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

i am trying to link my face book account with button,the hyperlink is working but 
  it's not opening my logged in page,i want to open my logged in page by clicking 
  on face book.
  Thanks

```
<a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/login/ use this link.

Answer (score 0):

You need the correct directory:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Rex-Khan/" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you are already authenticated to Facebook, you should be able to hyperlink to [facebook.com/home.php](https://www.facebook.com/home.php) to get to your authenticated dashboard.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/home.php">Facebook</a>
```

---

If you are not already authenticated Facebook will redirect you to [facebook.com/login.php](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhome.php) requesting you to login then redirect you back to your dashboard when authenticated.

If you're wanting to link users to your public Facebook account. You'll need to go to your Facebook profile, and copy the hyperlink in the address bar.

example:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/{YOUR FACEBOOK USERNAME OR ID}">Facebook</a>
```